# view a file's git history directly from an emacs buffer

Tags: git, emacs

I'm often interested in seeing a file's git history (e.g. run `git log <fname>`) while viewing that file in an **emacs** buffer.  Of course it's possible to just open a shell buffer and issue the command, but surely there must be some fancy-pants way to do this directly.

**The question:**

Do I need to install anything to do that, or is it a standard feature of modern emacs?

Comment: @wvxvw that key sequence is undefined in my environment - what am I missing?  Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: in case it helps: C-x v l runs the command vc-print-log, which is an interactive
autoloaded compiled Lisp function in `vc.el'.

It is bound to C-x v l, <menu-bar> <tools> <vc> <vc-print-log>.

Comment: I guess the emacs installation I was using predates "forever", or had been stripped down.  It happens :)  Thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `vc` is included in Emacs. Its keybindings start with `C-x v` (hit `C-x v C-h` to see all of them), and the one for viewing the history of a file is `C-x v l`, for `vc-print-log`.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for magit, it's really handy.
http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Magit
You can install it with el-get or package.el.